# Why my flutter socket.io client is not connecting to node.js socket.io live server

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am not able to connect to my live socket.io live server using
***socket_io_client 2.0.0***

this is the code for the connection

```
String url = "my server url";

  late io.Socket socket;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    initializeSocket();
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    socket.disconnect();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void initializeSocket() {
    try {
      socket =
          io.io(url, <String, dynamic>{
            "transports": ["websocket"],
            "autoConnect": false,
          });
      socket.connect();  //connect the Socket.IO Client to the Server

      //SOCKET EVENTS
      // --> listening for connection
      socket.on('connect', (data) {
        print(socket.connected);
      });

      //listen for incoming messages from the Server.
      socket.on('message', (data) {
        print(data); //
      });

      //listens when the client is disconnected from the Server
      socket.on('disconnect', (data) {
        print('disconnect');
      });
    }
    catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

When this code runs
**socket.connected**  always returns false, which means socket is not connected to the server.

Comment: What version of Socket.io server are you trying to connect to?

Comment: Is your node.js server is live, if it is not then you must have received an XHR poll error

Comment: Yes my node server is live and running

Comment: I am using the socket.io version 4.1.2

Comment: I suggest you to catch the errors with: `socket.on("error", (data) => print('error'));`. What did you got? If you compile your application to a real device, you must make sure the device has access to the development environment. You can use local proxy like Charles for this.

Comment: Ya I did it ```socket.on('connect_error', (data) { print('connectionerror');
print(data);});```   and found that there was an exception ***WebSocketException: Connection to url was not upgraded to websocket***,  and there was a problem in the apache configuration in the server. So after modifying my configuration  my socket.io client was connected to socket.io server successfully.

Comment: Great! For other folks, I meant to use this to catch errors: `socket.on('connect_error', (data) => print(data));`.

Answer (score 0):

Check with the postman (Desktop Version)
The reason of not connecting maybe your client is using different version of websocket than the server.
Both client and server should use same version in order to connect.

Comment: I tried to connect with postman but the reponse is                         Status Code: 400 Bad Request

Comment: it seems there is problem in server endpoint.